# Not able to store null in Future<CustomModel> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable   `late Future<QuestionModel> question;` and a function that fetches QuestionModel

```
fetchQuestion(){
    // Question model is initialised here
}
```

It is being used in build to display a UI

```
          FutureBuilder(
              future: question,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return LoadingWidget(
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("Something went wrong");
                }

                QuestionModel question = snapshot.data as QuestionModel;
                return Container(),
                  );
                }
            ),
```

Which is working fine.

In the UI itself I have a button which sends data to backend and fetches new QuestionModel from Firestore. Which is also working fine.

Requirement: To Show loading screen after clicking a button and avoid reclicking till the new QuestionModel is fetched but I don't want to create a separate `isLoading` variable for that.

I just want to reset the questionModel which was initialised earlier  as `questionModel = null`  and show loading screen by making use of futurebuilder itself as I already have LoadingWidget attached to my FutureBuilder.
But that is not possible as Future can't be null with below error

```
A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<QuestionModel>'.
```

---

EDIT 2:
In other words I want to uninitialize the future to trigger my Future builder to show loading Widget.

Comment: Use setState while setting new value in question

Comment: It takes 3-4 second to fetch a new data till than I want to show loading screen and hide the UI as people tend to click on it again if the UI is there. I already have loading widget in Future builder so I want to set my question variable as null but that is not possible as it is a future.

Comment: Instead of null assign the new future

Comment: if possible, can you share sample with how to assign a new future to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

try the demo here to understand more

#### https://dartpad.dev/?id=3dadbc210baaf70d405b75e5389c7ba8

---

you can use `setState` to rebuild the `FutureBuilder`.

But there are behavior for `FutureBuilder` will not execute the `future` method when you define it as `local state variable`

solution:

- define the Future method not as state variable. you can put in on any file. for example in your `helper.dart`

```
Future<String> apiCall() async {
  print("apiCall is executed...");
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  return Future.value("${Random().nextInt(100)} update");
}
```

then in your `FutureBuilder` widget, use condition for `ConnectionState.waiting`,

and every time you call `setState` the `apiCall` will executed

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: localFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          return Text("${snapshot.data}");
        }
      })
```

ps: if you use `snapshot.hasData` , it will be `true` even the `apiCall` not finish yet. better to listern the connection state.

Comment: I have no issue in updating the UI but I just want to reset my future to null to change the UI to show LoadingWidget till new data is fetched and avoid resending data to firebase. I have also updated my question with more details for better understanding.

Comment: No, Whenever my UI is rebuilt an API call is made. So, that is against the best practices as it could lead to multiple API calls and defeat the purpose of assigning future in separate function and will cost more money and increased bandwidth. I just want to fetch the question on initState or when I explicitly click on button.

Answer (score 0):

Change declaration to this : `late Future<QuestionModel>? question;`

Change your code to this :

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: question,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return LoadingWidget(
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("Something went wrong");
                }

                QuestionModel? question = snapshot.data as QuestionModel;
                return Container(),
                  );
                }
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this instead: (As FutureBuilder keep rebuilding whenever we call setState, we should not use it.)

1. Declare QuestionModel as nullable variable

```dart
QuestionModel? question
```

2. Create function to fetch the question, For example:

```dart
  void _loadData() {
    setState(() {
      question = null;
    });
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
      var questionResult = await your_service.fecthQuestion(); // Your defined function to fetch the question
      question = questionResult;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

3. Called it inside initState

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

4. You may create the widget to something like this

```dart
Widget _buildBody() {
    if (question == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    return Center(child: Text('My Widget'));
  }
```

5. Last but not least, you can fetch new question on button click by calling _loadData(), and the screen will show loading until the question is being fetched successfully.